# How to rewrite current route in asp.net mvc with new route data values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my site.master, i need to be able to rewrite the current route to match a mobile site.

Basically i need to be able to do this:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("home", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", environment = "d1" })%>
```

but i need to know the route name and values on each page request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jousterling

In case anyone is still wondering how to do this, apparently you can't get the route name

from Phil Haack:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/28/getting-the-route-name-for-a-route.aspx

but you can register a data token with the route name and then extract that later.